# Packaging Issues PyInstaller of Python application with Oracle Database Connection

Tags: python, windows, oracle, pyinstaller

I am trying to package a python application using pyinstaller. I am using cx_oracle and the oracle instant client to connect to an oracle database. I am working on Windows 10. My application works fine before I package it. But after packaging, the following error occurs when I try to run the executable file:

**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1072: the Oracle Client library version is unsupported**

This error occurs in the line `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"instantclient_19_9")`. According to the ODPI log, the Oracle Instant Client is loaded successfully, but while validating, the error occurs.
The problem is not due to a different Oracle Instant Client version on the system. I have checked for other versions on the systems, but there are none. Also, when I remove the Oracle Instant Client that I am trying to load, a different error occurrs, which says that not Oracle Instant client was found.
When I package the application while mocking or omitting the database connection, the packaging works fine.

I have tried everything on two separate systems, on which I experience the same issues. Another person could reproduce my issues as well. Also, I can replicate this error with the following **toy example**:

There needs to be no Oracle database present. The Oracle Instant Client needs to be installed into the folder where the following file is located.

```
import cx_Oracle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"instantclient_19_9")
```

How I packaged:

- Go to some folder, to which you want to package the application. I'll call it ministaller.
- Make sure it is empty.
- python -m PyInstaller --name application C:\path\to\application.py
- python -m PyInstaller application.spec
- The exe is located in ministaller\dist\applicationfolder. Call it via cmd to see the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on the PyInstaller GitHub, and the answer given there solved the problem for me:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5572

Comment: Can you share the output from DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL=64 when you were having the problem, before you set PATH?  This may let us see where we can improve cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Triple check the correct Oracle client is being loaded. Set the environment variable DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to 64 before starting Python.  (See the [cx_Oracle Initialization documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html)).  This will show how cx_Oracle is looking for the Instant Client libraries, and will let you make sure there is no other (older) oci.dll somewhere on the computer that is being used.

Check you are on a supported OS version (i.e not Windows 7).

Check you have all the Instant Client libraries (obviously you don't need JDBC files): https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/instant-client.html#GUID-6895DB45-97AA-4738-9959-BD677D610186

Make sure the computer has the correct VS Redistributable installed.

Comment: Thank you, but I already checked most of this. The link should be helpful though either way.